# Uniswap v3 Subgraph Returning Empty Array for TokenHourDatas

Tags: uniswap

Hey I'm trying to get a response from the v3 subgraph. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting an empty array back for this query on the WETH contract

```
{
  tokenHourDatas(where:{ token:"0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"}) {
    id
    open
    close
    high
    low
    priceUSD
    token { 
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The token string needs to be all lowercase